# Convert Json that has many unicode characters back to standard json

Tags: c#, json, unicode, urldecode

I'm receiving a json payload from a webhook but the json that is returned is coming in like this

> payload=%7B%22event%22%3A%7B%22info%22%3A%22REFRESH.INTERIM_PROGRESS%22%2C%22loginName%22%3A%22sbMemKostaSavR4%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22providerAccount%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A10376130%2C%22providerId%22%3A12292%2C%22isManual%22%3Afalse%2C%22createdDate%22%3A%222017-08-20%22%2C%22aggregationSource%22%3A%22USER%22%2C%22refreshInfo%22%3A%7B%22statusCode%22%3A0%2C%22statusMessage%22%3A%22OK%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22IN_PROGRESS%22%2C%22additionalStatus%22%3A%22ACCOUNT_SUMMARY_RETRIEVED%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D

is there a simple way to convert it back to normal standard json with the curly braces. I really don't want to do a crazy `string.Replace` method on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily with build-in java function:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("YOUR_ENCODED_STR", "UTF-8");
```

No need any external library.3

Comment: Thanks for that, using c# though.